# How to use high dimensional features for random forest in scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

How can I use high dimensional features for random forest in scikit learn?
I intend to use a 10 dimensional feature vector and mahalanobis distance between vectors.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A 10 dimensional feature vector is not really high dimensional. Also, how do you intend to use Mahalanobis distance with Random Forest?

Comment: a random forest consists of decision trees.at each node of the tree is a decision based on a comparison. for each comparison we need a distance. I intend to use mahalnobis distance for finding the distance between the feature vectors and use them for the decision tree.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) only Gini and Entropy criteria are available to grow classification trees. However you might be able to code up a new criterion yourself and use it.